# Percentile Ranking by Grouping in R

Tags: r, excel

[image: My Dataframe is as follows:]
[image]

The column ID is a sequence of 1-63 in repetition. I wish to add two new columns Closepctl and Quantitypctl in which I can rank each entry from 1-63 i.e., on the basis of Close and Quantity column but grouped with respect to  ID. Is there any way to do this in R?

I tried it in excel but failed to find any grouping option there. Excel approach is also appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when you're asking a question.

Comment: And please provide data as plain text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following is helpful...

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)    
df <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(RankSepal = percent_rank(Sepal.Length), 
         RankPetal = percent_rank(Petal.Length))
```

Comment: `dplyr` also has the `percent_rank()` function, which may be what the OP was looking for (based on the title of the question).

Comment: The question is updated. If you don't mind, please try on this example.